# MultiValueDictKeyError at /login 'username' on entering credentials

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have created a login page, but whenever I enter credentials, it shows me `MultiValueDictKeyError` at username

My HTML login page is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/login">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table width="20%" bgcolor="0099CC" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <center><font size=4><b>User Login Page</b></font></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" size=25 name="Username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="Password" size=25 name="Password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form)" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div>
    {% for messages in messages %}
    <h3> {{messages}} </h3>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My views file is:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.info(request,'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login ')
else:
    return render(request,'login.html')
```

My URLs for views are :

```
from django.URLs import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('login',views.login, name='login'),
    path('registration',views.registration, name='registration'),
]
```

Error shown :

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /login
'username'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'username'
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 78
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\siddh\\projects\\telusko',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python38.zip',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\DLLs',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python38',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 8 May 2020 07:27:41 +0000
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tips

The error means that the the key 'username' has no value: So,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username', None)
```

So, if there is no `username` key from the request, `None` will be assigned to username.

## Main error

Your error is in template:

```
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<!-- name=Username to username -->
<td><input type="text" size=25 name="username"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<!-- name=Password to password-->
<td><input type="Password" size=25 name="password"></td>
</tr>
```

*Note:- Main thing you have to learn from this problem is **MultiValueDictKeyError**. You have to understand that, the error is shown when there is no matching key, but you are trying to access value from that key.

Comment: now it is showing that no reverse match found for login, below written is the error displayed NoReverseMatch at /login
Reverse for 'login ' not found. 'login ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'login ' not found. 'login ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Absolutely right error is because of difference of name in views.py and in HTML form. Thanks @Biplove

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
username = request.POST.get('Username', '')
password = request.POST.get('Password', '')
```

please note that **'U'** in username and **'P'** in password are capital letters.

Comment: now it is showing that no reverse match found for login, below written is the error displayed NoReverseMatch at /login
Reverse for 'login ' not found. 'login ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'login ' not found. 'login ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: use **redirect(reverse('login'))** in place of **redirect('login')**
you can import reverse using below line.
**from django.urls import reverse**